# Update of multiple events in a single ics file(icalendar stream) using php

Tags: php, icalendar

After adding multiple events in a single ics file, I have used the given code for updating multiple events in a single ics file. But its not working. The events are not updated. Any body please help me. My code is given:

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";    
$ical .= "\nVERSION:2.0";    
$ical .= "\nPRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN";    
$ical .= "\nMETHOD:REQUEST";    
$ical .= "\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN";    
$ical .= "\nX-WR-RELCALID:asjh675adashdh";    
$ical .= "\nX-WR-CALNAME:My Nov Calendar";   

foreach($arr as $newArr){
    $ical .= "\nBEGIN:VEVENT";    
    $ical .= "\nUID:" . md5($newArr['stDate']) . "example.com";    
    $ical .= "\nSEQUENCE:1";    
    $ical .= "\nDTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd');    
    $ical .= "\nORGANIZER:catalog@example.com";    
    $ical .= "\nDTSTART:".$newArr['stDate'];    
    $ical .= "\nDTEND:".$newArr['stDate'];    
    $ical .= "\nSUMMARY:".$newArr['sub'];    
    $ical .= "\nDESCRIPTION:".$newArr['desc'];    
    $ical .= "\nCLASS:PUBLIC";    
    $ical .= "\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED";    
    $ical .= "\nTRANSP:TRANSPARENT";    
    $ical .= "\nEND:VEVENT";    
}

$ical .= "\nEND:VCALENDAR";    
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');    
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=my-calendar.ics');    
echo $ical;    
exit;
```

I have also change the SEQUENCE number but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

What property does change in each event ?

Your UID property is based on the DTSTART of each event. So if you change the start of the event, the UID changes. UIDs must not change when updating an event. It is the one thing that should remain constant for the whole lifecycle of the event.

Dont know what gmdate('Ymd') does exactly but DTSTAMP are supposed to be YYYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ format.

Then you are missing a METHOD=REQUEST parameter in the content-type header but I dont think that is causing the failure to update.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But I have used an static array called $arr, where values are static, therefore DTSTART value for each UID remain same. 

DTSTAMP is also accept YYYYMMDD value which I have used through gmdate('Ymd')

And lastly I have already used METHOD=REQUEST at the begining of my code. Please check.

So please let me know what I have to do for update multiple events in a single ics file using PHP

Comment: DTSTAMP MUST be in zulu. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.7.2 . As far as the METHOD, I'm talking about the content-type header, not about the iCalendar property. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6047#section-2.4